# Converting seconds into HH:MM:SS format

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert seconds(int) into `HH:MM:SS` format in SQL Server?

e.g. 90 should output => 00:01:30

**UPDATE**

I have two dates `START_DATE` AND `ENDDATE`.

I want difference of these dates

Also finally I want to sum up these differences in `HH:MM:SS` format

FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39c2b/1/0

Comment: If there is a difference of 20 days between the Start & End date = 480hours; how do you represent it as HH:MM:SS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @Seconds int;
set @Seconds = 90;
select replace(str(@Seconds/3600,len(ltrim(@Seconds/3600))+
abs(sign(@Seconds/359999)-1)) + ':' + str((@Seconds/60)%60,2)+
':' + str(@Seconds%60,2),' ','0')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
      declare @sec int
      set @sec=10

      select
          convert(varchar(5),@sec/3600)
           +':'+convert(varchar(5),@sec%3600/60)
           +':'+convert(varchar(5),(@sec%60));
```

**update** 
for data as hh:mm:ss  use "replace"

```
             declare @sec int
             set @sec=90

     select
          replace(convert(varchar(5),@sec/3600)
            +':'+str(convert(varchar(5),@sec%3600/60),2)
            +':'+str(convert(varchar(5),(@sec%60)),2),' ','0');
```

for example look here [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/4270)

Comment: leading zeros are not taken care of. For example, @sec=62 will return 0:1:2 and not 00:01:02

Comment: yep I want 00:02:20 instead 0:2:20

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is the `TIMESPAN` concept in SQL. However, there is no TIMESPAN variable in T-SQL.  Instead, you can use the following concept.

I would not use the ElapsedSecond as the storage variable (although it works). The reason is that to represent TIMESPAN effectively, it is best to store it as DATETIME. This way, you get all the flexibility of a DATETIME variable. For example, you can do a `YEAR( @TimeSpan)`, `MONTH( @TimeSpan )`. It will be harder to do that if you have the ElapsedSecond stored.

To illustrate the concept in T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '1/1/2013 1:01:58'
SET @EndDate = '1/5/2013 7:02:00'

DECLARE @TimeSpan AS DATETIME
SET @TimeSpan =  @EndDate - @StartDate

PRINT   CONVERT( VARCHAR, (DATEDIFF( DAY, 0, @TimeSpan) * 24) + DATEPART(HOUR, @TimeSpan) )
        + ':' + RIGHT( '0' + CONVERT( VARCHAR, DATEPART( MINUTE, @TimeSpan ) ), 2)
        + ':' + RIGHT( '0' + CONVERT( VARCHAR, DATEPART( SECOND, @TimeSpan ) ), 2 )
```

Notice that in the above, you can use the `DATEPART()` function and work on the TimeSpan just like any `DATETIME` variable. This is much more flexible and important as you get into more details.

Another advantage is a **NEGATIVE** Timespan. If you use the ElapsedSecond method, the function will **fail**, while a TimeSpan will survive.

Answer (score 0):

This may help - good example to subtract time portion and more. You can add/sum...:

```
Select start_date, end_date, time_diff,
   EXTRACT(DAY FROM time_diff) days,
   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time_diff) hours,
   EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM time_diff) minutes,
   EXTRACT(SECOND FROM time_diff) seconds
From
(
Select start_date, end_date, end_date - start_date time_diff
From
(
Select CAST(to_date('21/02/2012 06:10:00 am', 'dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mi:ss am') AS TIMESTAMP)  end_date
     , CAST(to_date('01/01/2012 12:00:00 am', 'dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mi:ss am') AS TIMESTAMP) start_date
From dual
))
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a valid .NET timestamp. Code is non optimized though.

```
create function [dbo].to_timespan(@secs as int) returns nvarchar(16)
begin
    declare @mins int, @hours int, @days int;
    set @days = @secs / (60 * 60 * 24);
    set @secs = @secs - @days * (60 * 60 * 24); 
    set @hours = @secs / (60 * 60);
    set @secs = @secs - @hours * (60 * 60);
    set @mins = @secs / 60;
    set @secs = @secs - @mins * 60;
    return replace(str(@days, 2) + '.' + str(@hours, 2) + ':' + str(@mins, 2) + ':' + str(@secs, 2), ' ', '0');
end
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to return HH:MM:SS string output from the differences of two DATETIME values is to use the built in T-SQL date/time functions.

```
DECLARE
    @Start_Date DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND, -86399, GETDATE())
  , @End_Date DATETIME = GETDATE();


SELECT 
    CONVERT (VARCHAR(8), 
    DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, @Start_Date, @End_Date), 0), 108) 
    AS ElapsedHHMMSS;
```

OUTPUT:
23:59:59

Note however that if you're dealing with more than 1 day, you probably want a different output besides HH:MM:SS.  This maxes out after 24 hours, but 24:00:01 isn't appropriate output anyway for this format.  Some of the other responses above will produce an invalid 24:00:01 like output.

Answer (score -1):

```
    select to_char(to_date(90,'sssss'),'hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

try this mate