# SSRS: How do I get the duration between two "datetime2" values without fractional seconds?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have two values as "datetime2" datatypes. I want my report to read "Start Time", "End Time", "Duration". If I simply subtract the two values, I get a warning saying the '-' operator isn't valid for datetime2 and the output looks like "00:01:01.5000760".

I can use DateDiff('s', starttime, endtime) to get the duration in seconds. How would I then format that into "dd:hh:mm:ss" for display? I'd like to stay away from modifying the stored procedure, hopefully all this can be done within the expression builder.

Comment: already answered in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116821/converting-seconds-into-hhmmss-format

Comment: @RameshYelda - These questions are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
=Floor(DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!StartTime.Value, Fields!EndTime.Value) / 86400) &":"& Format(DateAdd("s", DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, Fields!StartTime.Value, Fields!EndTime.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

You add this optionally at the end

```
 + " DD:HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: That first line of code works perfectly, gets my string in the perfect format. What would the optional "DD:HH:mm:ss" do?

Comment: @MooseLogic it just adds DD:HH:mm:ss after the duration, i.e. "0:02:01:10 DD:HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score -1):

right click that field cell, choose `Expression`, using `FORMAT` function.

Something like below:

`= FORMAT(Field!col.Value, "dd:hh:mm:ss")`